# How does the double-buffered canvas know when to swap the buffer?

Tags: html5, html-canvas, double-buffering

How does the HTML5 canvas know that all the drawing operations are complete and it's time to swap the buffer ? Program can have multiple draw calls at different places so how will it know when is the right time to swap the front and back buffers ?

Comment: why do you think it's double buffered? It just displays the stuff you draw to it the second it has some downtime

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, the browser lets you know when it's ready to paint the next frame via [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Usually, your "draw" calls happen within this callback.

In traditional games using double-buffering, the [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) itself dictates when the [page flip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Page_flipping) occurs. A simple game loop might look like this:

```
loop {
    update()
    draw()
        // all the draw calls happen here
    flip()
}
```

So it doesn't matter where the draw calls are, at the game loop level it's well defined when they occur - usually between the `update` and `flip`.